Python serial receives data packets at a lower rate than they are being sent
I set up a test where two uart-to-usb adapters are connected together. I send 14 byte data packets at a rate around 100 Hz. The receive thread only seems to be able to operate up to around 60 Hz though. I've verified with a logic analyzer that the data is sent at the correct rate.
I've been poking at this a bit and I have a very simplified test code below that just checks serial.in_waiting for a value change. This was in an attempt to remove any other process that might be eating up my time.
My test code :
port1 = 'COM3'  
port2 = 'COM4'  
baud_rate = 115200
packet_size = 14  # Size of each packet in bytes
packet_interval = 0.01  # Interval between packets in seconds (10 ms)
number_of_packets = 100
# Generate test data to send in each packet
test_packet = b'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:packet_size]

def sender():
    with serial.Serial(port1, baud_rate, timeout=1) as ser:
        start_time = 0
        for _ in range(number_of_packets):
            ser.write(test_packet)
            ser.flush()
            time_taken = time.perf_counter() - start_time
            print(f"Sent {len(test_packet)} bytes in {time_taken:.6f} seconds. {1/time_taken:0.6f} Hz")

            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            # sleep_time = max(packet_interval-time_taken, 0)
            time.sleep(packet_interval)

def receiver():
    with serial.Serial(port2, baud_rate, timeout=1) as ser:
        ser.reset_input_buffer()
        received_data = b''
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        prev_data_in_waiting = 0
        while True:
            data_in_waiting = ser.in_waiting
            if(not data_in_waiting == prev_data_in_waiting):
                print(f"data in queue {data_in_waiting}")
                prev_data_in_waiting = data_in_waiting
                dt = time.perf_counter()-start_time
                print(f"freq : {1/dt}")
                start_time = time.perf_counter()
                
            time.sleep(0.001)


# Start sender and receiver in separate threads
start_time = time.perf_counter()
receiver_thread = threading.Thread(target=receiver)
sender_thread = threading.Thread(target=sender)

receiver_thread.start()
sender_thread.start()


receiver_thread.join()
sender_thread.join()



total_time = time.time() - start_time
print(f"Total time for data transmission: {total_time:.2f} seconds")


Anyone have any insight into what the issue might be?

I tried sending 14 bytes of data at a rate of 100 HZ
I expected to receive 14 bytes of data at a rate of 100 Hz
I received data at a rate of about 60 Hz

Seems like it is due to how the FTDI chip operates
https://www.ftdichip.com/Documents/AppNotes/AN232B-04_DataLatencyFlow.pdf
It has a 16ms delay which is why im seeing about a 63 hz update rate.

The FTDI can go up to rates of 1 kHz if you take the latency timer down to 1ms. This is accessible from the device manager in windows.

The FTDI can go up to rates of 1 kHz if you take the latency timer down to 1ms. This is accessible from the device manager in windows.
Windows Menus
